# How to run a single MediaWiki on many servers?

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I couldn't find a tutorial on this, all I found was info on how to run multiple wikis from one server. Issues are things like high-speed shared storage for images between servers and good performance with some sort of centralized caching.

Does anybody know of any guides?

Comment: Did you try https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family ?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to give advice to such vague requirements, but doing my best.

Image storage: what are the storage/load needed? For a Wikipedia-sized cluster the only solution known to work is OpenStack Swift, however it's a huge PITA to use so NFS is probably the sane choice.

Shared caching: memcached.